How to programmatically bypass the re-ordering policy of the function's stack
I want to dump the function's stack.
I believe I can achieve so through GNU C built-ins such as __builtin_frame_address
But not all of them are supported. This is why I use some ASM to retrieve the base pointer and the current stack pointer after the local user variables are declared.
/* Get pointer (stack_end and stack_start are temporarily global pointers) */
__asm__ __volatile__("mov %%rsp, %0" : "=r"(stack_end));

/* User variables */
volatile int    integer     = 4960;
volatile double real        = 5.53;
volatile char   character   = '!';

/* Get the base pointer (rbp), which is the start of the stack frame */
__asm__ __volatile__("mov %%rbp, %0" : "=r"(stack_start));

Subtracting stack_start from stack_end gives us the current stack size.
Now I can dump it and inspect it. However, even though the variables were declared as volatile the '!' is  for some reason ordered before 5.53, as you can see here:

How can I create a buffer containing the values of these variables in order (without packing them into a structure, because I want to retain the ability to initialize them with a value like that)?

volatile has nothing to do with where it is being allocated. It has to do with how it is accessed. Moreover, the compiler does not necessarily respect volatile for stack variables (it is arguably a bug though)

Bottom line, I'd say you cannot. Perhaps you should describe what you are trying to achieve instead.

@EugeneSh. I thought so too, but it was worth trying. As for what I am trying to achieve, this is one of the key components for my attempt to loosely simulate CPP-alike Object Oriented constructs in C as part of my large C extension library.

Probably not my business, but I'd say a library should be architecture-independent (unless it is architecture-specific library...)

@EugeneSh. You are absolutely right. There is no denying. I will be aiming to make it as much portable as possible, but at this point it will be useful if it at least works for me, since I use it for other cool projects I would like to share with the world :)

@EugeneSh. I have never noticed it. Can you provide an example where the compiler does not honour volatile on automatic storage duration variable?  https://godbolt.org/z/8bjGbY685

@Edenia it cant be portable as C language does not know anything about the stack. It is an implementation detail

@0___________ Usually, I would abuse GCC extensions, defines, attributes and built-ins to write a completely different system-specific code under conditionals. In this case though, I am unconvinced that there is another approach to this problem so I might end up with code that remains equally as unportable.

@0___________ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380510/non-conforming-optimizations-of-volatile-in-gcc-11-1

@EugeneSh. "This is a far-fetched example." I do not think it is an error

@0___________ In the comments to that one, I linked another:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55457835/arm-compiler-5-do-not-fully-respect-volatile-qualifier (well, it's less of a main-stream compiler though)

@Edenia - We all know that Bjarne tried to add classes to C using macros, and it failed miserably. Trying this again 50 years later seems like perhaps not the best idea.

Yeah well, I was expecting you to say that. But just because Bjarne couldn't, does not inherently mean that I can not. The question that arises is whether I should keep pushing until I have something meaningful. I personally like and use C as-is, but then sometimes you wish you could have classes after all. But hey, there is GObject.

I personally like and use C as-is, but then sometimes you wish you could have classes after all. For that, one possible way from my answer: Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C

@CraigEstey This is something completely different though - It does not simulate a cpp-like class definition. It would be very complicated to deal with the multitude of implications of such C magic. Also, the address of the structure object is guaranteed to be the address of the first member and in this question, the name field is always the first member, so you might as well just print it directly: printf("%s\n", *((char** )&obj));  Padding is not an issue there (C99, 6.7. 2.1p13)

I'm confused as to what you're really trying to do. The printf requires "incestuous" knowledge of the struct--not a good practice. And, incorrect. name is never the first element of the base struct. It is the second. And, in the final example, it is the third. As to "not simulating a cpp-like class definition", what do you think c++ actually does to impl subclasses? As to the "complications", if you really want to do such, do it with a metaprogramming preprocessing step

I don't know what "incestuous" means. it is an obscure term to me and I am not a native speaker. And no, like I said in the question name most definitely is the first member of the struct, and not the second with it being second in your answer. At this point I just think you are not reading carefully so I am not sure if there is a reason for me to elaborate further. And unfortunately subclassing is by far not the only concern and is in fact the least concern when it comes to simulating cpp-like class definitions (which is description is as straightforward as it can be)

Though, "subclassing" is very easy to achieve in C, with structure A to structure B type-casts with the structures being type-cast safe in the first place of course (with padding members or nested structures).

The only way to enforce a certain allocation order in standard C is to use structs or arrays.

There is no way to do it. Variables defined on stack can be actually located on the stack in any order. It depends on a compiler, on optimization and ultimately on Martian wind.
If you want to initialize or work in any way with several variables at once, you must organize them into a structure (packed or not). The structure does guarantee the order of its members.
If you have a function-unique set of variables and you do not want to create a project-wide stuct, you can actually create a localized structure:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void foo() {
    struct __attribute__((packed)) {
        char a;
        short b;
        char c;
    } st;

    memcpy(&st, "a\1\0B", sizeof(st));

    printf("a=%c b=%d c=%c\n", st.a, st.b, st.c);
}

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}

That way, you can create a function specific structure with all variables in it stored in exactly the order you defined.

But that violates the "without packing them into a structure" constraint and this defeats the point of everything. As for the order, what if you declare/define each variable in a separate scope? I have not tested that, but theoretically this might encourage the compiler to lay out data consecutively on the stack. Also, talking about strict C, I am pretty sure this is indeed impossible, but in GNU C, with the enormous amounts of extensions I was hoping for miracles haha.
